# Routing with query leading to "This page could not be found" - Nuxt JS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

My main page is displayed when entering the url:

```
http://localhost:3000/?param1=param1&param2=param2
```

In some condition I change the route to

```
this.$router.push("/success");
```

and the new url is:

```
http://localhost:3000/success
```

In this new page I have a button that I want it to lead me back to the main page

```
<n-link :to="{path:'../', query: {param1:'param1' ,param2:'param2'}">
  <div class="return-button">Return to Main Page</div>
</n-link>
```

after clicking the button, the url is changes to the currect url:

```
http://localhost:3000/?param1=param1&param2=param2
```

but what is displayed on the screen is:

> This page could not be found

When i'm refreshing the page, its loading correctly, searched for solution and found nothing about it.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you change the path to `/`? You shouldn't need to specify the `..`.

Comment: if I change the path to "/" it leads me to "success/?param1.....".

Anyway I just found the solution, I update it in the question

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that says I need to add "**replace**" to the end of the tag, and instead of "../" in the path, add just "/".

It looks like this:

```
<n-link :to="{path:'/', query: {param1:'param1' ,param2:'param2'} }" replace>
  <div class="return-button">Return to Main Page</div>                  ^                                                                       
</n-link>                                                               |
```